# Creating a clickable dropdown menu with HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, click

I am currently working on a project using only HTML & CSS. I am wanting to make the menu button only display the dropdown items when it is clicked, and have an "x" button that will close them when it is clicked.  I am able to make the menu dropdown on hover but am having no luck with it on click without JavaScript.

Does anyone know how I might be able to do this with just HTML & CSS? Here is the HTML & CSS that I have as of right now:

```css
.header-menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.header-menu-items {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.search {
  display: none;
}

.search-icon {
  display: none;
}

.header-menu-items hr {
  color: #d0d0d0;
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
}

.header-menu-btn {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ff3b3b;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.header-menu:hover .header-menu-items {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div className="header-menu">
  <button className="header-menu-btn">Menu</button>
  <div className="header-menu-items">
    <div>
      <a className="a" href="">
         Shirts
         </a>
      <hr />
      <a className="a" href="">
         Pants
         </a>
      <hr />
      <a className="a" href="">
         Shoes
         </a>
      <hr />
      <a className="a" href="">
         T-shirts
         </a>
      <hr />
      <a className="a" href="">
         Accessories
         </a>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all it has to be `class` and not `className`.

What you want to do can be achieved with a `checkbox` and the sibling selector `~`.

```css
.header-menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.header-menu-items {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.a {
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.search {
  display: none;
}

.search-icon {
  display: none;
}

.header-menu-items hr {
  color: #d0d0d0;
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  height: 1px;
  border: none;
}

.header-menu-btn {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ff3b3b;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: block;
}

#toggle-menu {
  display: none;
}

#toggle-menu:checked ~ .header-menu-items {
  display: block;
}

#toggle-menu ~ label .hide {
  display: none;
}

#toggle-menu:checked ~ label .show {
  display: none;
}

#toggle-menu:checked ~ label .hide {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-menu">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-menu"><label for="toggle-menu" class="header-menu-btn">Menu <span class="show">show</span><span  class="hide">hide<span></label>
  <div class="header-menu-items">
    <div>
      <a class="a" href="">
         Shirts
         </a>
      <hr />
      <a class="a" href="">
         Pants
         </a>
      <hr />
      <a class="a" href="">
         Shoes
         </a>
      <hr />
      <a class="a" href="">
         T-shirts
         </a>
      <hr />
      <a class="a" href="">
         Accessories
         </a>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Javascript onclick simulation using only css and html (without javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851023/javascript-onclick-simulation-using-only-css-and-html-without-javascript)

I know your answer is in the answer to this post but I can't really figure out how to do it myself.

It would require changing your button to an input tag of checkbox type and going from there.

Comment: That should be a comment or a vote to close as duplicate. It in its current form is not an answer.